# Want to create a composite pdf document from other documents and then add dynamic forms

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, fpdi

I'm creating an incoming invoice processing tool for my accounts department.
Basically i want to take the incoming invoice (a pdf of unknown size and shape) and insert it into my template pdf. 
So basically I end up with a document (that is always A4, portrait) and that has all the fields the accounts department wants to fill in all available.
I can see how to do that much FPDI easy enough>

Forgive the psuedo code:

```
new FPDI
import template.pdf
import invoice.pdf
FPDI -> New page
useTemplate template.pdf
useImportedPage invoice.pdf (fit to bounding box)
save output.pdf
```

That works fine. What I want to do next is add dynamic form fields so they can be digitally filled.

TCPDF allows you to create forms, so that's cool. But I don't see how / if I can pass my FPDI object to TCPDF. Any one have any thoughts?

Comment: You know [this](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/installation/#index-2-2)?

Comment: I... did not. Missed it. Thanks that was it!